# Connect to OpenVPN server via Azure VM as a client

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtual, gateway, openvpn

I'd like to connect to an OpenVPN server through my Azure VM. In the beginning I simply downloaded openVPN to my machine and started the client using a client.conf file but that didn't work - I always get a DNS error. I used:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@client
```

So I tried to find some more info and from what I understand so far, I need to eastablish a point-to-site connection as described here:
[Setup OpenVPN point-to-site connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-openvpn-clients)

But it does not tell me, how to simply use a .conf file and setup up the virtual network gateway correctly to connect to a server.

Can someone give me a hint that I'm on the right track here?

Edit:

Thank you for input. But I'm still kinda stuck here.
I setup everything, virtual gateway with open vpn but the link you posted only explains how to use the gateway to connect from a local computer to a openvpn server as far as I understand.

What I want to to is connect from an Azure VM to receive data from the server. I already have all the certificates and keys setup and now like to connect from my VM.

My client file looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote example.openvpn.net 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
explicit-exit-notify 3
keepalive 1 5
user root
group nogroup
ns-cert-type server
verb 3
# auth-user-pass credentials.txt
auth-user-pass "/etc/openvpn/credentials.txt"
auth-retry nointeract
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure open VPN First you need to setup Point-to-site vpn connection. A Point-to-Site (P2S) VPN gateway connection lets you create a secure connection to your virtual network from an individual client computer. A P2S connection is established by starting it from the client computer. Here is the reference to setup point-to-site [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about#:~:text=A%20Point-to-Site%20%28P2S%29%20VPN%20gateway%20connection%20lets%20you,location%2C%20such%20as%20from%20home%20or%20a%20conference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about#:%7E:text=A%20Point-to-Site%20%28P2S%29%20VPN%20gateway%20connection%20lets%20you,location%2C%20such%20as%20from%20home%20or%20a%20conference).

And then you can setup open vpn connection in linux systems as per this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-openvpn-clients#linux

unfortunately i don't see any direct way to use a .config file to setup a vpn gateway to connect to your server.